# how can i serialize a property to element with a default attribute

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I need to serialize this class with a property to xml, the property need to come as an element with the name of property as value for an default attribute.

> ```
> class RequestDto
> {
>     public string ZipCode {get;set;}
> } 
>
> as 
>
> <RequestDto>
>     <Parameter name="zipcode"> </Parameter>
> </RequestDto>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that via `XmlSerializer` directly from the shape of that object model; basically, `XmlSerializer` assumes that your model and xml will be *more or less* the same. Implementing `IXmlSerializable` is frankly not worth it. I would suggest using `XDocument` to serialize that instead:

```
string zip = "abc";
var el = new XElement("RequestDto",
    new XElement("Parameter",
        new XAttribute("name", "zipcode"),
        zip
    )
);
```

Which gives (via `.ToString()`):

```
<RequestDto>
  <Parameter name="zipcode">abc</Parameter>
</RequestDto>
```